# Ao clicar em botão, aumentar ou diminuir altura de uma div

Tags: javascript, css

Criei um botão dentro de uma div (`#divteste`) e gostaria que ao clicar no botão essa div(`#divteste`) aumentasse o `height` e ao clicar novamente no botão diminuisse o `height` e se tiver como ultilizar uma trasição ou animate.

[image: Meu código atual]

Comment: [Manual de como **não** fazer perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/4808).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tente com o animate assim

```
$('#seuBotao').on('click', function(){
    if($('.sua-div').height() == 30){
         $('.sua-div').animate({"height" : "200px"}, 200);
    }else{
        $('.sua-div').animate({"height" : "30px"}, 200);
    }
});
```

Onde 200 seria o tempo em milissegundos para a animação;
Pode também criar adicionando classes:

```
 $('#seuBotao').on('click', function(){
        if($('.sua-div').hasClass('pequena')){
             $('.sua-div').animate({"height" : "200px"}, 200);
             $('.sua-div').removeClass('pequena');
             $(this).attr('value', 'Diminuir');
        }else{
            $('.sua-div').animate({"height" : "30px"}, 200);
            $('.sua-div').addClass('pequena');
            $(this).attr('value', 'Aumentar');
        }
    });
```

Comment: tentei aqui mais nao to conseguindo

Comment: Adicionou a biblioteca jquery ao seu site?

Comment: pronto funcionou eu estava colocando o codigo no local errado

Comment: Ta animando do jeito que você quer?

Comment: teria como mudar o valor de dentro do botao? tipo aumentar e quando aumentasse aparecesse diminuir

Comment: Editei  a reposta, basta alterar a propriedade value do botão em cada evento